# Core 2.0 Application not falling into If statement in cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

This is my first attempt at creating a Core 2.0 MVC application.  I have the following in my `index.cshtml`:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-   
            action="Register">Register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

When `User.IsInRole("Admin")` is true, it does not fall into the `if` statement.  I have even tried the following and it still doesn’t fall into the statement

```
@if (1 == 1)
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-
             action="Register">Register</a>
        </li>            
    </ul>
}
```

I only want to show the Register link if the current user is an admin.  Why isn’t it falling into the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, which suggests something in the build/deploy stages.

What happens if you make a change to the index outside the if?
What happens when you put a breakpoint in and step through the code?

Comment: When i make content changes to index.cshtml it look fine.  Builds without errors.  When i put a breakpoint inside the if, it's never hit.  When i step through it, it does not fall into the if statement.